# In which suttas did Lord Buddha teach nihilism is better than eternalism?

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon

I read the Lord Buddha taught nihilism is better than eternalism.

In which Pali suttas is this teaching found?

Please provide quote the relevant suttas. Please do not give personal opinions.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

In [AN 10.29](https://suttacentral.net/en/an10.29), it said:

> *(8) “Bhikkhus, of the speculative views held by outsiders, this is the foremost, namely: ‘I might not be and it might not be mine; I
>   shall not be, and it will not be mine.’ For it can be expected that
>   one who holds such a view will not be unrepelled by existence and will not be repelled by the cessation of existence. There are
>   beings who hold such a view*

In [Iti 49](https://suttacentral.net/en/iti49), it is said:

> *And how, bhikkhus, do some hold back? Devas and humans enjoy being, delight in being, are satisfied with being. When Dhamma is taught to
>   them for the cessation of being, their minds do not enter into it or
>   acquire confidence in it or settle upon it or become resolved upon it.
>   Thus, bhikkhus, do some hold back.*
>
> *"How, bhikkhus, do some overreach? Now some are troubled, ashamed, and disgusted by this very same being and they rejoice in (the idea
>   of) non-being, asserting: 'In as much as this self, good sirs, when
>   the body perishes at death, is annihilated and destroyed and does not
>   exist after death — this is peaceful, this is excellent, this is
>   reality!' Thus, bhikkhus, do some overreach.*

In these suttas, the Lord Buddha teach nihilism is better than eternalism because eternalism is based in lust, bondage, delighting & clinging, which are dirty defilements (*kilesa*/กิเลส).

Comment: In the first paragraph it is talking about end of Samsara. So in a Buddhist context it would be those who accept the existence of Nibbana and those who do not. It is not talking about anihilationism. How does the 2nd paragraph imply annihilationism is better?  You seem to have a knack for misinterpreting the suttas. My advice is to you is stop thinking of yourself as a teacher and find a good Theravada teacher and study under him.

Comment: Obviously "holding back" is worse than "overreaching" because the over-reacher is seeking what is "peaceful" while the holder-back is full of lust.

Comment: It is not in this context as there's no reason to do good deeds if everything ends at death. Those who believe in life after death would usually do good deeds to make the next life better

Comment: Wrong. Buddhists who believe in life after death are murdering people, such as Rohingya & Tamils, in Burma & Sri Lanka. Christians & Muslims have been murdering people for 100s of years. Burma & Thailand had many wars. Tibetan monks murder eachother.

Comment: Murdering has nothing to do with believing in life after death.  It's like saying "people who drink water rape women" :)

Comment: You have refuted your own argument; when you say "Murdering has nothing to do with believing in life after death" because this is the same as saying: "Not murdering has nothing to do with believing in life after death"

Comment: It's not the same.  Because a person who believes in Karma has an additional reason not to murder as he would fear being born in hells. This is not to say that his reasoning may not  be overcome by hatred. But a person who does not believe in life  after death would usually be concerned about how to do it secretly without anyone noticing.

Comment: Not true because monks, such as Bhikkhu Bodhi, have made a case for "Just War" or "Holy War". The Buddha taught kamma is intention therefore many Buddhists, such as in Burma, Sri Lanka & the USA, believe the intention to preserve a Buddhist nation via war is good kamma.

Comment: You were wrong saying the first paragraph it is talking about end of Samsara. Please read the 1st paragraph in my answer again. The Buddha defeated you in debate here because the Buddha said in AN 10.29 the view of nihilist is the foremost among the views of outsiders.

Comment: Intention to preserve a Buddhist nation is indeed good Karma. But thinking that murdering will preserve Buddhism is bad karma as it involves wrong view.

Comment: I does not matter if it is wrong view. My point is that Buddhists that believe in future lives still kill people in war. This shows you are wrong. Hindus, Buddhists, Christians, Muslims have been at war for 100s of years.

Comment: You are doing it again. If you can understand Sinhala, try to get a [Sinhala copy of the sutta](http://www.metta.lk/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/2Majjhima-Nikaya/Majjhima2/060-apannaka-s.html) and read. Buddha never said nihilism is foremost in AN 10.29 .

Comment: People kill in  the name of religion because of wrong views. Not because of belief in afterlife :)

Answer (score 5):

Lord Buddha never said nihilism is better than eternalism.

**It's actually the reverse as Nihilism comes under Niyata-micca ditti**. It both blocks the path to heavens and blocks the path to Nibbana. **That is why it is called [Saggavarana](http://theeyeofdhamma.blogspot.com/2013/07/the-moral-conduct-that-is-free-from-any.html)**, whereas eternalism is only called Maggavarana(blocks the path to Nibbana)

Answer (score 2):

Buddha never said that nihilism is better than eternalism.
What he said was that people who take Rupa as self is more sensible than the people who take Nama as self because the mind is changing faster than the matter.

Comment: Can you reference a sutta in which this is said?

Comment: Hi, Chris sorry I can't find the Sutta reference right now.

Comment: [SN 12.61](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn12.61): “It would be better, bhikkhus, for the uninstructed worldling to take as self this body composed of the four great elements rather than the mind. For what reason? Because this body composed of the four great elements is seen standing [...] for a hundred years or even longer. But that which is called ‘mind’ and ‘mentality’ and ‘consciousness’ arises as one thing and ceases as another by day and by night"

Comment: This answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is in [Dīghanakasutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.074.than.html), that is memorized by sariputta's students at 1st saṅgāyanā.

**However, buddha neither taught to develop nihilism nor eternalism at all.**

Comment: Please quote from the sutta.